# Making Colored Text Invisible

Tags: fonts, formatting, color

I want to be able to create worksheets that can essentially toggle via minimal modification from being

a) blank worksheets to give to the students for an assignment
b) keys to those worksheets to give to students after they have turned in the assignment
c) grading rubrics with points assigned to different items in the key.

My thought is that constructing the rubric (which includes everything from the blank worksheets and the keys) using black text for the original problem statement, blue text for the solution to the problem, and red text for the point assignment would provide a primary document.  From this document, if I could force the red text to become invisible, the result would be the key.  Similarly, if I could force both the red and blue text to become invisible, the result would be the original blank worksheet.  For the sake of clarity, when I say invisible, I mean leaving the remaining text exactly where it had been and not shifting it just because the other text is no longer generated in the PDF.

Is there a command, say something like \bluetext{off} or \bluetext{on} that could be placed towards the beginning of the document that would turn "off" the blue text, leaving the space the blue text took up intact but making the text invisible?  Same idea for the red text?

I have included a small example of a rubric below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\title{Worksheet}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{problem}[\textcolor{red}{2 points}]
Let $f(x)=3x^2-5x$, find $f'(x)$.
\end{problem}

\textcolor{blue}{f'(x)=6x-5}\hspace{0.25in}\textcolor{red}{1pt per term}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you used a custom macro rather than `\textcolor`, you could redefine it to something like `\phantom`. You could also use custom colour names and then let them to `red` or to `white`, say, but that wouldn't be good if you provide electronic copies to students.

Comment: There are also some packages and classes which are designed for this kind of thing, but I don't know if you've looked at those or not.

Comment: are you distributing pdfs or paper? do you need to make the invisible text just invisible (eg white) or do you need to make it not extractable from the pdf?

Comment: See also the transparent  package.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I meant you could redefine the command to use `\phantom` - not name the command `\phantom`.

Comment: ah yes that is in fact what you said, sorry (I'll delete)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use, say, `\solution{}` rather than `\textcolor{blue}{}`, then you can do something very simple: define `\solution{}` in your preamble with two lines and keep one commented out. Then you just change which is commented out according to whether you want the text to be visible or not. By redefining `\solution{}` to use `\phantom{}` you cause it to insert space which takes up the same area as the original text would have.

For example,

```
\NewDocumentCommand \solution {+m}
{%
%   \textcolor{blue}{#1}%
  \phantom{#1}%
}
```

will render the solutions invisible, while

```
\NewDocumentCommand \solution {+m}
{%
  \textcolor{blue}{#1}%
%   \phantom{#1}%
}
```

will typeset them in blue.

Similarly, you could do something like

```
\NewDocumentCommand \points {+m}
{%
%   \textcolor{red}{#1}%
  \phantom{#1}%
}
```

but I am not sure if this is really what you want since you will still get the parentheses at the start of the `problem` environment, but with nothing inside them. It seems to me you would typically not want the number of available points to be invisible even in the worksheet version, so perhaps you want simply to render this text normally and use `\points` only for the rubric break down within problems?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{problem}[theorem]{Problem}

\usepackage{pgfplots}


\NewDocumentCommand \solution {+m}
{%
%   \textcolor{blue}{#1}%
  \phantom{#1}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand \points {+m}
{%
%   \textcolor{red}{#1}%
  \phantom{#1}%
}

\title{Worksheet}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{problem}[\points{2 points}]% or do you want just '2 points' or '\textcolor{red}{2 points}' here?
Let $f(x)=3x^2-5x$, find $f'(x)$.
\end{problem}

\solution{f'(x)=6x-5}\hspace{0.25in}\points{1pt per term}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, that helps a lot.  Commenting out one of two possible definitions to allow the definition to toggle between blue/red text and "phantom" is perfect.